# Suddenly asp.net project is not recognizing AJAX extensions

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Several years ago I created an asp.net web page with VB2010 that runs on our company's web server. It has been running with an Ajax script manager and an Ajax update panel. It has been working fine for years.

Today when I needed to make a change in the code, the IDE is suddenly showing errors not recognizing the script manager or the update panel. (Edit for clarification: The errors showed up before I even made any changes to the code.)

For a test, I added an Ajax timer to the page, and the IDE flags that as unrecognized also.

All of the answers I have found online, including here, refer to making changes to the aspx code or to the web.config file, but I am hesitant to do that because it has been working fine all this time without needing those changes.

To my knowledge, nothing has changed since the last time I made changes to the application. It sounds like something may have been corrupted, but I have no idea where to look.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: missing references or DLLs in the project seems most likely? Did you download it from source control and they got missed? A specific example of the controls not working and the exact error message you're getting would make this a lot less ambiguous. Also, if you're wary of making changes...just make a copy first. Or if you have it in source control, just revert anything which doesn't help.

Comment: I don't use source control, but since you mention it, I have discovered that the bin folder has mysteriously disappeared. How can I fix that? Would it work if I copied the bin folder from the website into my development folder?

Comment: Probably, if you're sure the source is the same version as what's deployed. Or try re-adding the project references. Don't you have backups of your source code??

Comment: Yes, I do have backups. In my panic, my mind didn't even go to that. I'll check it out.

Comment: @ADyson Well now I am confused. Checking my backups as far back as July last year, there is no bin folder for that project.

Comment: Hm, odd. Like I said, have you tried re-adding the relevant project references? If you're still stuck, show us some code and error messages.

Comment: What I did was restore that entire directory from the earliest backup after a change, which was in November last year. The errors are still there. I don't really know what code to show you, and the errors are 'unknown server tag' for asp:ScriptManager and asp:UpdatePanel.

Comment: And, again, check your project references. Do you have a reference to System.Web.Extensions in the project references? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx document the namespace and assembly to which these controls belong.

Comment: Yes, it's there, and to make sure, I added it again. Still not working. I am thinking about starting all over, because I am anticipating some pretty extensive changes anyway.

Comment: does a "Clean Solution" and "Rebuild Solution" help?

Comment: I'm not seeing a clean, and a rebuild doesn't do it. I think I am doing something wrong. This shows up as "Website" on the vb2010 menu bar, and my other applications show up as "Project." It has been a while since I have worked on this, so I'm starting to think I loaded it wrong.

Comment: @ADyson I just created a whole new project and copied the code over, and that seems to work fine. I only wish I knew what caused the problem. Thanks for your help!